# Why this.tick() is returned. React Tutorial

Tags: reactjs

I'm relatively new to web development and am currently studying Reactjs.

My question is regarding this code. This is found on the React.js website, here specifically: [State and Lifecycle - React](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

```
    this.timerID = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }
```

I'm wondering why `this.tick()` has to be returned. instead of just `setInterval(this.tick(), 1000)`. I tried this, and of course didn't work.

Comment: Did you try: `setInterval(this.tick, 1000)`

Comment: yes it shows type error

Comment: setInterval wants a function as the first parameter. If you add this.tick() as a parameter, then you runs the tick function right away because the parentheses . So your first parameter will be whatever your tick method return, most probably void.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as per [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval), the first argument is supposed to be a `function`. That answers my question.

So, that was why, when I tried to write:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
  }
```

it didn't work...

But when I `bind` it like so,

```
class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
```

it worked.